# How to find voltage gain of below analog circuit without using Nodal analysis?

Tags: circuit-analysis, bjt, feedback, loop-gain, nodal-analysis

[image]

This is a theoretical circuit just made to see that if I can find voltage gain of circuit and it took me much calculations then anticipated to get voltage gain.I just want to find if there is better way then nodal analysis to solve this question.

This is an arbitrarily made circuit where Q point is already found using using DC analysis so I didn't mention power supply.The transistor is operating in active region and the value of collector current at Q point is mentioned in description of BJT.

Comment: Is there no power source for this circuit?

Comment: Circuit appears to be a common-emitter amplifier with a feedback resistor. What you'll need to solve is what type of negative feedback your system is, i.e. series-series, series-shunt, shunt-shunt, shunt-series. (On a side note, I'm pretty confused that you've labeled your input voltage as \$v_o\$ and your, presumably, output voltage as \$v_o\$. If these values are indeed equal then wouldn't your gain simply be 0dB?)

Comment: Have you just drawn this arbitrarily?

Comment: How in the heck do you get \$r_o=100\:\Omega\$?? Is \$V_A=5\:\text{V}\$? (I don't think I've seen many of those.)

Comment: Some fundamental errors in this design exist.  try again.

Comment: If you want the small-signal transfer function linking the collector voltage to the input voltage, you must first transform your circuit with the hybrid-\$\pi\$ model. Then, one quick solution is to apply the extra-element theorem (EET) with \$R_3\$ as your extra element. The result is given in equation (3.90) page 140 in the book *Linear Circuits Transfer Functions*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fklrmk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is Common Emitter design, H bias with negative feedback design, not perfect for every variation on Rin,Rout, gain and V+ , but one that closer matches what you were trying to do with up to 50x more voltage gain.  ( assuming you meant to show Rc on V+ but didn't know how to use editor.)

Practical gains are up to 50 but 100 is possible with more distortion like H bias.

Comment: Sunnyskyguy, the circuit may work - however, did you include intentionally the resistor Rb? It looks rather uncommon. Normally, we have either Rb or Rf but not both.