# Bypassing an AC signal in a common emitter amplifier without a bypass capacitor

Tags: amplifier

[image]

We all know that we use a capacitor across the lower resistor (Re2) so that the AC will be bypassed through the capacitor and hence no (almost) AC voltage drops across the 2.7k.

If that is the case why don't we connect the other terminal of the AC source as shown in the picture so that we do not need to bypass the AC at all?

The AC generator terminal is connected in between Re1 and Re2, does that mean the AC ground has moved to that point between Re1 and Re2? If that is the case then is it fair to say that R1 and R2 are still connected to AC ground? The ac ground has now shifted. What is the fundamental difference in AC and DC ground in the amplifier context? From the beginning I have been considering AC and DC grounds the same in the CE amplifier context.

Comment: If the voltage source V2 was actually the output of a previous amplifier stage, how could this connection have been made ? In other words, how would you use this method when the voltage source doesn't preset two leads for connection ?

Comment: In other words, you don't always have the option to reference the source to an arbitrary node in your circuit. It's much more common that both circuits have the same reference.

Comment: @AJN but terminals of the voltage source is clearly shown.

Comment: @DaveTweed thats fine but how about the circuit? will it replace the usual capacitor bypassed circuit? or is it completely different?

Comment: The clearly shown terminals of the voltage source will be present in the physical circuit, if the voltage source represented a bench power supply or a function generator. If it represents something else like the previous stage of a multistage amplifier, the actual device will not have two leads coming out of it. Only one lead, and other implied lead being the common or the ground node.

Comment: I do not like to see wires running all over the place.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ftf2.png

Comment: It's completely different. The bypass capacitor creates an "AC ground" at the junction of Re1 and Re2 for both the base current AND the collector current. Your proposed configuration only does this for the base current. The AC component of the collector current will be flowing through Re1 + Re2, greatly reducing the "headroom" (voltage swing before saturation) of the output.

Comment: @Dave Tweed let me make one thing clear, I have connected negative of the ac source to the junction of Re1 and Re2 because I thought doing so will pass the ac component only through Re1, because the ac source is connected between base and the resistor junctions, I do not understand why and along which path AC component will still flow through Re2? is this because here in this case AC and Dc grounds are the same,  and hence electrons will flow out of the ac ground which is dc ground as well, and will flow through its usual path ground then re1 then re2 then emitter etc?

Comment: @Dave tweed also I thought shifting the negative terminal of the ac source will also move the AC ground of the circuit wherever newly shifted negative terminal is. But it looks like it doesn't matter where I have shifted the negative terminal of the ac source, the AC ground will be remained fixed at the same place wherever it was previously : in this case it is the point of DC ground. The idea came because I had assumed the AC ground has moved. But it's not. Please let me know if that's the reason

Comment: You speak of "**the** AC ground" as if there can be only one. But there are two sources of AC current in the circuit, the current produced by your voltage source and the amplified current produced by the transistor itself (powered by the DC voltage source). You need to analyze these current loops separately. Even if you call the junction of Re1 and Re2 "ground", that second current is still flowing through Re2.

Comment: You have already entered the circuit into a simulator -- what did you find when you ran the simulation? Try it both ways.

Answer (score 2):

The assumption you must make is the signal source is floating and has not reference to your circuit ground otherwise the schematic is inaccurate.  Also the sig.gen. return line has illogical jogs in the path. if it was not floating is actually grounded then you could invert the source and ground the input and apply signal to the emitter R junction for the same result using a series cap then the equivalent circuit is that series cap and C1 shunting the emitter resistor Re2.

Result=no benfefit and both caps now need to be twice as large in series as the Re2 cap would be.

However if your signal truly a voltage source with Rs=0 and 0V DC you could direct couple to the base with a series Rb to base and move R1 from V+ to the collector for negative feedback and get a Av= Rfb/2Rin .

- with that you can delete/bypass Re2 and make Rc/Re1 <=75 rather than 33:1 (Rc/Re2) and try to get a gain of 30 from a R ratio of 60 such that the other resistor bias Vc output to V+/2. R2 would be increased to adjust the output to this voltage.
- since the open loop gain is low, and input current is non-zero,  the gain error is about 1/2 of Rfb/Rin ratio when optimized for DC bias.
- this way you get far better linearity and eliminate the caps with “direct coupling”
- If your source is not 0 ohms but allows some DC current pullup, then include the source resistance in the Rin calculation.
- Remember that negative feedback lowers the input impedance to almost Rin and lowers the output impedance of Rc by the amount of feedback gain (>3). that also benefits reducing the 1/2 or less loss with Rl=Rc with a lower output impedance.
- If you balance the R values well this also extends your full scale output swing.
- R2 moves from gnd to V+ to help bias base current with Rfb with a higher value
- This circuit I explained [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/444085/how-to-find-voltage-gain-of-below-analog-circuit-without-using-nodal-analysis/444135?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C50.6512#444135)